# OS Scheduler Interval Timer - Where does it run? How to interact with it?

Tags: process, operating-system, scheduler, freertos, rtos

As it relates to process scheduling by the OS: I understand that the scheduler requires a "clock" like device, known as an interval timer, to keep track of the amount of time used by each process and when to switch to a ready process.

My question is - where does the interval timer run? It seems like it needs to be running constantly, parallel to any processes, so that it can always keep track of time, including the amount of time being used by the running process. But as we all know only one thing can run on a CPU at any one time, and if the process is running, it means the interval timer cannot run. So therefore, is the interval timer implemented in hardware rather than software? And if so, if I was building a custom OS and scheduler, how would I access and communicate with it in my custom scheduler code?

Comment: It is a,hardware timer that generates an interrupt, just like all the other perpherals that can generate interrupts and cause a rescheduling, eg disk, kb, ,mouse, network hardware.  Google 'interrupts'.

Comment: 'I understand that the scheduler requires a "clock" like device, known as an interval timer' wel, not absolutely.  It is quite possible to implement a system that runs on I/O completion interrupts only.  The timer is so useful for for timing out system calls, sleep intervals and the like that it is pretty universally implemented.  It also has the side-effect of sharing out the CPU resource when there are more ready threads than cores.

Comment: @MartinJames is this hardware timer a chip on the motherboard separate from the CPU, like the Intel 8253/8254? or nowadays is it implemented within the CPU itself?

Comment: @doofus It's inside the CPU currently.

Comment: Most MCUs have multiple on-chip timers.  ARM Cortex-M devices have a SYSTICK timer specifically intended for RTOS scheduling in the core rather then as a peripheral - leaving MCU timers available for other purposes such as PWM generation, or event timing/counting or timing at a higher resolution than the RTOS clock might support or need.

Answer (score 1):

The "interval timer" as you call it is a *hardware timer*.  It generates an interrupt at a fixed period.  When the "RTOS tick" interrupt occurs, the tick handler (typically):

- increments the tick counter,
- updates any running *software timers*,
- if a task delay or software timer expires, any task blocked on that becomes *ready*,
- the scheduler is run, the highest priority ready task runs.

Note that this is not the only time the scheduler runs. For example scheduling occurs whenever a task explicitly suspends on a delay, timer, semaphore, mutex, event flag, or mailbox for example.  Any RTOS call that causes the running task to *block*/wait causes the scheduler to run.

> And if so, if I was building a custom OS and scheduler, how would I access and communicate with it in my custom scheduler code?

You would simply configure the hardware timer to generate the tick interrupt and proceed as above.  You might take a look at an existing open-source RTOS to see how it is done.  Although FreeRTOS which you tagged is not exactly conventional. uC/OS-II may be a better starting point - it is deliberately simple and was originally implemented to teach RTOS design and implementation.  The associated book describing the kernel is freely available in PDF form at https://weston-embedded.com/micrium-books.